# C and C++ odd syntax "unsigned int :32;"

Tags: c++, c

What does this line of code mean:

```
    unsigned int                   :32       ;
```

It comes from:

```
      typedef struct avr32_pwm_channel_t {
      union {
              unsigned long                  cmr       ;//0x0000
              avr32_pwm_cmr_t                CMR       ;
      };
              unsigned long                  cdty      ;//0x0004
              unsigned long                  cprd      ;//0x0008
        const unsigned long                  ccnt      ;//0x000c
              unsigned long                  cupd      ;//0x0010
              unsigned int                   :32       ;//0x0014
              unsigned int                   :32       ;//0x0018
              unsigned int                   :32       ;//0x001c
    } avr32_pwm_channel_t;
```

I try googling it but found nothing

Comment: thanks I'm reading about it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called bit-field. It determines the width of each memeber of the struct.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field.

Comment: how can we Distinguish those 3 members of the struct then ??
             `unsigned int                   :32       ;//0x0014
              unsigned int                   :32       ;//0x0018
              unsigned int                   :32       ;//0x001c`
since they have no names, can you please explain them more.

Comment: Those are some padding bits.

Comment: aha ... thank you 
also this link explains it better than the wiki 
http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/bitfields.html